# How to find the maximum height with a loss of 5 J of energy due to air drag

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, projectile, drag

Can someone please help me to figure out how to use the 5J of energy into my equation for the maximum height.  I know that the maximum height is given by,

$$h_{max}={(v_f-v_i)^2 \over 2g}$$  but I'm not sure how to factor in the air drag in Joules. My question is a basic rock with mass $m$ being thrown up vertically with a $v_i$ and to find the vertical height maximum it reaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the $5$ joules means over the course of its entire trip. So the rock will lose $2.5$ joules on its way up. Then the gravitational potential energy at the top of its trajectory minus the $2.5$ joules should be equal to what other energy term?